# Python-'<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python

Hi I am new to coding and i've just started. I have seen many examples of the same error but I am unsure how to apply that to my code. I am trying to sort a text file in order of score. This is my current code:

```
ScoresFile = open("Top Scores.txt","r") 
newScoresRec = []
ScoresRec = []
for row in ScoresFile:
 ScoresRec = row.split(",")
 username = ScoresRec[0]
 Bestscores = int(ScoresRec[1])
 newScoresRec.append(username)
 newScoresRec.append(Bestscores)
 ScoresRec.append(newScoresRec)
 newScoresRec = []
sortedTable = sorted(ScoresRec,key=lambda x:x[1])
for n in range (len(sortedTable)):
 print(sortedTable[n][0],sortedTable[n][1])
ScoresFile.close()
```

The text file is just in the simple format of:

'username','score'-
example: BO15,78
Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Comment: Print `ScoresRec` before sorting and see its contents. Does it have all integers in second items?

Comment: so basically it means that you are comparing a string with integer which you cannot do. also can you show txt file? also show the complete error

Comment: Given that you have a CSV and want to sort a column, and maybe do other operations, pandas would be useful

Comment: There is ScoresRec = row.split(",") and after that ScoresRec.append(newScoresRec). Why you appending something to ScoresRec and reassign it in next iteration? Your logic is very complicated, and I can't understand many things here. I recommend you rewrite it and simplify. Try to write code without lamdas if you just starting with programming. And refactor code with lamdas after check simple one. That will be a good practice. If you want, I can answer, but that will different code than yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and let me know if it works:

```
scores_rec = []
with open("Top Scores.txt", "r") as scores_file:
    lines = scores_file.readlines()

    for line in lines:
        s_line = line.rstrip().split(",")
        scores_rec.append([s_line[0], int(s_line[1])])

sorted_table = sorted(scores_rec, key=lambda x: x[1])

for item in sorted_table:
    print(item[0], item[1])
```

Comment: Should be `line.rstrip().split(",")`, but you don't need `readlines`

Comment: Ah you're right. As for the read lines, I think it makes it a bit easier to follow still having a for loop but what would you do

Comment: file handles are iterable. Theres no need to have an intermediate list

Answer (score 0):

Part of the issue is that you're appending back into the split list,

```
ScoresRec = row.split(",")
...
ScoresRec.append(newScoresRec)
```

and not building a list of lists; at the end of the loop, you are sorting the last line of the file with the two appended values that you added

Therefore, you are sorting a list of a few strings and a list, with the sort key being a list containing a string and int, thus the error.

Answer (score 0):

Text file (`file.txt`):

```
"MORETHANSMALLER",2
"BIGGER",10
"SMALLER",1
"UNDERBIGGER",9
"MIDDLE",5
```

Code (`csv_reader.py`):

```py
import csv

with open('file.txt', newline='') as csvfile:
  rows = list(csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"'))
  rows.sort(key = lambda x: int(x[1]))

print('From 1 to 10:')
print(rows)
rows.reverse()
print('From 10 to 1:')
print(rows)
```

Result:

```
From 1 to 10:
[['SMALLER', '1'], ['MORETHANSMALLER', '2'], ['MIDDLE', '5'], ['UNDERBIGGER', '9'], ['BIGGER', '10']]
From 10 to 1:
[['BIGGER', '10'], ['UNDERBIGGER', '9'], ['MIDDLE', '5'], ['MORETHANSMALLER', '2'], ['SMALLER', '1']]
```

Don't parse CSV files manually. Use python CSV libraries. That will help you to avoid traps with quotes.